# Найти неизоморфные деревья с n-вершинами

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы, дискретная-математика, дерево

Добрый день!

Нужно написать программу, которая строит все неизоморфные деревья с n-вершинами. Я вижу примерный алгоритм следующим образом:
1) Найти кодировки всех деревьев с n-вершинами. Пока разобрался с двоичным кодированием по левому краю (вниз - 1, вверх 0). Например, дерево: 11110000. 
2) Из всех кодированных деревьев найти только те, которые являются изоморфными. Такую закономерность пока не нашел. 
3) Декодировать деревья и визуализировать их.

Возникает вопрос со вторым пунктом. Какая особенность у всех изоморфных деревьях? Как их вычленить из всех деревьев? И еще интересует, как узнать количество неизоморфных деревьев с n-вершинами?

Comment: Здесь лабораторки или подобное не решают

Comment: Приведите свой код

Comment: Вопрос, как я понял, в теории, так что и ответ следует искать там же. Смотрите определение изоморфизма графов вообще и деревьев в частности

Comment: Мне нужны ответы на вопросы только по теории в области дискретной математики, написать программу я потом смогу сам.

Comment: @nick_n_a решают. Читайте правила сообщества. Вопрос в том: человек хочет разобраться или схалявничать. Это -- другое дело. В первом случае следует помочь. Во втором -- нет.

Comment: @Zepar Вы обратились несколько не по адресу. Вам, вероятно, следует сходить на другой форум stackoverflow. Можете посетить dxdy.ru